# How to write this symbol for a Banach algebra?

Tags: symbols

How to write the following symbol in LaTeX

[image]

that's used for Banach algebras.

Comment: `$\mathfrak{E}_p(I)$` with `amssymb`

Answer (score 2):

It is a fraktur "E".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\mathfrak{E}_p(I)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Interestingly, while http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html is usually very good with this, I was not able to get auto-recognition of the fraktur E.

[image]